# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer Excel 2007 Format

Tags: excel, pear

I am using PEAR's [Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer) to generate excel file. It works fine.

Now we need to make the excel file 2007 format so that can be opened in more devices, such as ipad.

Can Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer generate 2007 excel file format at all? or we have to switch to http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having trouble in pear's spreadsheet_excel_writer. Can you please help me in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEAR's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer will only generate BIFF5 format (Excel 5.0) - BIFF8 format .xls files. If you want to write Office Open XML Spreadsheet files (.xlsx) then you will need to switch to a different library, such as PHPExcel, or develop your own/extend Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer yourself, or switch your method completely (e.g. to use COM instead).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the Open XML Library.

There are way's to use it from PHP:
https://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/8499.aspx